# Parse data into format based off common keywords

Tags: text-processing

I have a long list of file names that all end with .mp4xyz

```
12334,dogimage.mp4001
12335,dogimage.mp4002
12336,dogimage.mp4003
12347,cats.mp4001
12348,cats.mp4002
```

I need to convert the output into this format combining all images that share the same name. In this example I am only using `dogimage.mp4` and `cats.mp4` but there will be thousands of keywords.

```
a:3:{i:0;s:4:"12334";i:1;s:4:"12335";i:2;s:4:"12336";}
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"12347";i:1;s:4:"12348";}
```

The strings below represent:

`a:3` & `a:2` = The total amount of images

`i:0` = The image count for that keyword

Comment: This seems like a task that would be better suited for a freelance developer.

Comment: Is `i` to be derived from the `xyz` part of the extension, or from the order within the file? Or can these be assumed to be the same? Is the `s:4:` a fixed string?

Comment: No i:0 should be mp4001, i:1 should be mp4002, i:2 mp4003 and so on. s:4: is a fixed string yes.

Comment: Sorry yes that is correct it should be the xyz part mp4001 being first and so on. Not  the order of the files in the list, they may be jumbled.

Comment: That very much looks like  the output of [php's `serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), so it should be `s:5` here not `s:4` as those strings are 5 bytes long, not 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gawk:

```
BEGIN{

    # split by , or .mp4
    FS=",|\\.mp4"

    # sort array by numeric value
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
}

# store count in a, store others as key, value pair in d[keyword]
{ a[$2]++; d[$2][$3]= $1 }

END{
    for( keyword in d ){
        printf( "a:%d:{", a[keyword] )
        for( i in d[keyword] )
            printf( "i:%d;s:4:\"%d\";", i-1, d[keyword][i] )
        printf( "}\n" )
    }
}
```

**update**

To keep keyword order:

```
BEGIN {
    # split by , or .mp4
    FS=",|\\.mp4"

    # sort array by numeric value
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
}

{
    # insert next ordered number into loop_order upon new keyword
    if(!($2 in d))
        loop_order[k++] = $2

    # store count in a, store others as key, value pair in d[$2]
    a[$2]++; d[$2][$3]= $1
}

END{
    for (j = 0; j < length(loop_order); ++j) {
        keyword = loop_order[j]
        printf( "a:%d:{", a[keyword] )
        for( i in d[keyword] )
            printf( "i:%d;s:4:\"%d\";", i-1, d[keyword][i] )
        printf( "}\n" )
    }
}
```

Comment: This works however I need them to be in the order of filenames read from our list.

Comment: @Teddy291 see update.

Answer (score 2):

That's the output format of [php's `serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), so:

```
php -r '
  while ($line = fgets(STDIN)) {
    $n = strtok($line, ",");
    $image = strtok(".\n");
    $a[$image][] = $n;
  }
  foreach ($a as $v) echo serialize($v) . "\n";' < file.list
```

On your input, that gives:

```
a:3:{i:0;s:5:"12334";i:1;s:5:"12335";i:2;s:5:"12336";}
a:2:{i:0;s:5:"12347";i:1;s:5:"12348";}
```

(note the `s:5` instead of `s:4` as those strings are 5 bytes long, not 4).

To sort the list of arrays based on the keyword (lexically), insert of `ksort($a);` before the `foreach` loop, then the array for `cats` will be shown before the array for `dogimage` because `cats` comes before `dogimage` lexically.

Or maybe serialise the whole associative array so you don't lose the information about which array corresponds to which keyword like:

```
php -r '
  while ($line = fgets(STDIN)) {
    $n = strtok($line, ",");
    $image = strtok(".\n");
    $a[$image][] = $n;
  }
  echo serialize($a) . "\n";' < file.list
```

Which gives:

```
a:2:{s:8:"dogimage";a:3:{i:0;s:5:"12334";i:1;s:5:"12335";i:2;s:5:"12336";}s:4:"cats";a:2:{i:0;s:5:"12347";i:1;s:5:"12348";}}
```

Comment: This did not work as there are files called "cats2.mp4xyz" these should be separate.

Comment: @Teddy291, _separate_ from what? Do you mean they're called `cats2.mp4xyz` as opposed to `123,cats.mp4xyz`?

Comment: cats.mp4xyz & cats2.mp4xyz combined into one. They should bring back two results as they are different but similar keywords.

Comment: @Teddy291, they do for me with that code.

Comment: My apologies it does seem to be working but for some reason it's skipping 6 of the images. I am trying to find which are being skipped.

Comment: Is it possible to order the output based off the keyword in the file it reads? As you can see from this pastebin https://pastebin.com/txAv3W3t and an image of the files https://i.gyazo.com/7a1e2b8184118efea6a243c28534ad37.png the output is all jumbled.

Comment: @Teddy291, see edit.

Comment: Thanks that will help me find which are missing. Could you edit it so they are one line each?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it - using a hash-of-hashes in Perl:

```
perl -F, -lne '
  ($k,$i) = split(/\.mp4/, $F[1]); 
  $s{$k}->{$i-1} = $F[0]
  }{
  foreach $k (keys %s) {
    $hr = $s{$k};
    printf "a:%d:{", keys %$hr;
    foreach $i (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %$hr) {
      printf "i:%d;s:4:\"%s\";", $i, $hr->{$i}; 
    }
    printf "}\n";
  }  
' file
a:1:{i:0;s:4:"12334";i:1;s:4:"12335";i:2;s:4:"12336";}
a:0:{i:0;s:4:"12347";i:1;s:4:"12348";}
```

The "outer" hash `%s` is keyed on the keyword, while the inner anonymous hashes are keyed on the numeric value of the suffix (minus one) and have values taken from the first comma separated field of the line.

Note that the outer hash is unsorted so the order of output lines is not guaranteed.

Comment: Something went wrong here https://i.gyazo.com/29f75fcb24c9dc6b2e184d840d090664.png not sure what.